# excel Time function and cell format

Tags: excel, datetime, cell-formatting

For calculations within excel-2010 I need to add

```
 Cell A (format time - 13:30:55) (value = 10:01:02)
 to
 Cell B ( format Number) (value = 160)
=Which should result into
 Cell C (format time - 37:30:55) (value = 170:01:02)
```

This will tell me some kind of activity to 170 hours 1 minutes and 2 seconds of working time.

Can somebody suggest the formula for cell C?

Best Regards

Comment: Sure, it is a cell format in excel. Let me explain how I can see it. Please select the cell, right click, select format cell. The in the dialog select the Category Time and on the right hand side there are various Types listed. One of them in my excel-2010 version is 37:30:55.

Comment: True, it might be required but before that I need a formula to get the end result of 170:01:02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores date and time values ​​as days from 1900/01/01. The day 1900/01/01 is the value 1. Time values ​​are fractions of days. An hour is 1/24 of a day. One minute is 1/24/60 of a day. So if you enter 160 in an Excel cell and would like to include this as 160 hours in a calculation, then it must be done as 160/24.

The formula in C1 would be `= A1 + B1 / 24`

For cell formats it is better to specify in the custom form.

```
hh:mm:ss => 13:30:55
[hh]:mm:ss => 37:30:55
```

The brackets mean that the hours also include over 23.

Greetings

Axel

Comment: `[hh]:mm:ss => 37:30:55` is just an example, like `170:01:02` is only one possible value in this format. The German Excel shows just this example `37:30:55` in number formats dialog.